# Querying table elements by name using conditions in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and I want to create a custom query:
I have a table with products and these contain names like: "1224 banana" "951 chocolate".

I need to return a list of the products in descendent ordered by number ONLY.
like so:
"125 chocolate"
"12 apples"
"9 tomatoes"
"3 trousers"

I don't know if there's an special query for this or if I can create a custom query.

Comment: why don't you use one column for the quantity and another one for the products? It is hard to split a string in two using Mysql. Though it is possible to order your data using PHP after the query, I don't think it is the best way to do it. So: if you can't absolutely use two columns (and please explain why) then try to write the desidered query in MySql and post it here, then we can help you translate it into cakephp code

Comment: Yes, creating two columns is the "ideal" solution and it will be implemented in a while.
However, right now I need a "quick and dirt" way of solving this, that's why I came up with that solution.
However, your thoughts helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you should have 2 columns. (See [1Nf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form))

Here is a MySQL solution that orders by the leading integers that are separated by a space from the next values.

```
SELECT uglyColumn
FROM foo
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uglyColumn, ' ', 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Within CakePHP, you should just have to change your **find** method's order section to :

`'order' => array('CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uglyColumn, ' ', 1) AS UNSIGNED)')`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by arilia, I'm going to use an ordered array in the short-term. But in the near future I'm going to add a second field to separate the information.